# QTP results moved to other directory not opening

Tags: qtp

Hi i am trying to run QTP scripts using Test Batch Runner. The problem with this tool is that it is overriding results and only last script results are getting saved. So i have written a small snippet to move the results to some other folder after script runs successfully. but then the problem is that i am not able to open those results and it says could not load results. I am trying with QTP 11.
My code snippet

```
a=Environment.Value("ResultDir")
SystemUtil.Run "iexplore.exe", "http://www.google.com"
currentResultDir=Environment.Value("TestName")
Set qtpResultDir=Environment.Value("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
b="C:\result_dir"
qtpResultDir.CreateFolder(b)
qtpResultDir.CopyFolder a,b,True
```

Comment: Are you attempting to run this code from within QTP? You shouldn't be trying to mess with the result folder until the script has finished and exited. Also, how or in what are you trying to open the results in? What gives you the error message?

Comment: i am trying to open results in HP Resutl viewer. Yes i am trying to do this within the script and i also found out the possible reason too, which is that the result is partially generated and which is why after copying it is not opening. But then what is the solution to set results directory while running from Test Batch Runner?